# Leaderboard code doesnt wok properly discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so pretty much my code does work as long as only 1 person is in my JSON file. As soon as another user gets registered in the json file. I get this error: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'.

Any idea were my mistake is?

My code

```
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> mit {top_users[user]}\n'

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Rangliste")
    embed.add_field(name="Spieler", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You should not be using JSON as a database. It is recommended to use MySQL, MongoDB, or similar.

Comment: Share the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare dictionaries, which is not supported by default.

To fix this, you need to change your key function as it currently gives a `dict`.

```
# The following line gives an error because '<' is not applicable for item[1]
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
```

Note that the attribute you use should be comparable.

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["someattribute"], reverse=True)
```